# How to prevent input checkbox being affected by spacebar?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, focus

So, I've got this input of type checkbox for a dropdown menu on the top.
When I click on it and select something, for some reason clicking the spacebar toggles it on/off...clicking once elsewhere doesn't fix it either, I have to click outside twice.

I don't quite understand why I have to click twice outside, but regardless, I want to know how I can stop this from happening. I suppose I have to do something with focus...but I can't seem to understand it properly - nor do I know if that is indeed the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need the spacebar for your any button on the form, you can do an event.preventDefault() on keypress for the spacebar.

Comment: $(yourbuttonelements).keydown(function(e) {
        var kc = e.keyCode; 
        if (kc === 32){
        e.preventDefault();
        }
    });

Comment: nvm got it working without the dollar symbol, thank you very much

Comment: @TaufikRomadhon you have a typo in `event.preventDefaut()`. Should be `event.preventDefault()`.

Answer (score 0):

A better way i.m.o. is to reset the focus (or activeElement) at 'on click' like so:

```
// checkbox click handling
divWithCheckboxElement.addEventListener ("click", function() {

  // reset focus.
  document.activeElement.blur();
});
```

Why I think it's better?

1. When using preventDefault() the checkbox wil still be selected which
   looks akward because it has no function.
2. When resetting the focus, the spacebar can be used for other
   'keydown' hotkey handling. If the checkbox is still selected, other hotkey
   handling with the spacebar doesn't work.